# How can i write the pseudo code Algorithm in Latex?

Tags: algorithms

I would like to write pseudo code algorithm in Latex as in the attached picture.I have written code to make just like above algorithm but its not working for me. Is this code correct...

[image]

```
\IncMargin{1em}
 \begin{algorithm}
\SetKwInOut{Part 1}{input}
\SetKwInOut{Part 2}{output}
\Part 1{}
\BlankLine
\emph{abcdefgh $D$ ijklmnop}\;
\emph{ abcdefgh $A$}\;
\For{$k\leftarrow 1$ \KwTo $M$}{
            \For {each $m$ $ ∈ $ {1, 2, …, J}{
                \emph{ abcdefgh $D$}\;
                \emph{abcdef }\;
}
\Part 2{}
\emph{abcdefgh $A$ ijklmnop}\;
\emph{ abcdefgh $A$}\;
\For {each $m$ $ ∈ $ {1, 2, …, J}{
\emph{ abcdefgh $D$}\;
\emph{abcdef }\;
\emph{abcdef }\;
}
}
\For{$k\leftarrow 1$ \KwTo $M$}{
\emph{ abcdefghklmop}\;
\emph{ abcdefghklmop}\;
\emph{ abcdefghklmop}\;
}
\caption { Algorithm Sample}
\end{algorithm}
 \DecMargin{1em}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/359729/110998

Comment: Have a look at [LaTeX/Algorithms](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms) Copy some working sample code from this forum or from somewhere else from the internet and start modifying it. If you get stuck, post the code here and ask specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

The following is more in line with the regular syntax of [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\newcommand{\To}{\mbox{\upshape\bfseries to}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Algorithm sample}
  \textbf{Part 1}\;
  \nl abcdefgh $\{ D_i \}_{i = 1}^M$ ijklmnop\;
  \nl abcdefgh $A_m$\;
  \nl \For{$K = 1$ \To{} $M$}{%
    \ForEach{$m \in \{1, 2, \dots, J\}$}{
      abcdefgh $\{ D \}_m^t$\;
      abcdefgh\;
    }
    \textbf{Part 2}\;
    abcdefgh $\{ G_i \}_{i = 1}^K$\;
    abcdefgh $D_m$\;
    \ForEach{$m \in \{1, 2, \dots, J\}$}{
      abcdefgh $\{ G \}_m^y$\;
      abcdefgh\;
      abcdefgh\;
    }
  }
  \nl \For{$K = 1$ \To{} $M$}{
    abcdefghijklmno\;
    abcdefghijklmno\;
    abcdefghijklmno\;
  }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```